# Anylogic Null pointer Exception While updating/changing the scale of 3D Object during model Run

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, anylogic

I am using Anylogic Personal Learning Edition (PLE) for a school project
Anylogic allows to get the current scale value of a 3Dbject for example called "car" derived from agent let say called "mycar, during the model Run by using two methods;

```
    //staticAgent.getScale();
    mycar.getScale();         
                      Or
    //staticAgent.3DObj.getScale();
    mycar.car.getScale();
```

When i update/change the scale of my 3Dobject using

```
     //nonStaticAgent.setScale();
     mycar newCar = new mycar();
     newCar.setScale(0.5);

     //it gives following error during code compilation

     The method setScale(double) is undefined for the type mycar.
```

But, When i try with

```
    mycar newCar = new mycar();
    //NonStaticAgent.3Dobject.setScale();
    newCar.car.setSize(0.5);
```

it does not gives any error at compilation, but when i click buttton to change size by calling above mentioned method during simulaiton run it gives following

```
Error while executing user action
java.lang.NullPointerException
For more details see Console
```

```
At console
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gettingsize.Main.executeShapeControlAction(Main.java:435)
    at gettingsize.Main$4.action(Main.java:496)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeControl.executeAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeButton.executeUserAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.executeUserAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.a.onAction(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$null$3(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:71)
    at com.anylogic.engin.internal.webserver.d.acceptToAnimationSvgSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$startController$4(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:71)
    at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)
    at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
    at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:134)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.lambda$0(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter.doFilter(QoSFilter.java:202)
    at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.config.ALServerFactory$1.doHandle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create agents dynamically with the code you've to call "createAndStart(...)" function before change this agent size. For your case it may be:

```
mycar newCar = new mycar();
newCar.createAndStart(this);
newCar.car.setSize(0.5);
```